# Cannot display back button using modals on Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm reading the docs and they specify some extra configs for the modals, but nothing related with show/hide this back buttons.

Creating another project by default (conference one) it has this html:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{ item.name }}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

So no extra html is required in order to display this button.

I have configured my project with exactly same configuration (even translations) but doesn't work. I have the same html and js:

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(GameDetailsPage, {title: 'test'});
modal.present();
```

Why is this button not being displayed? Using Ionic 3.9.2

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Description
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button (click)="dismiss()">
        <span ion-text color="primary" showWhen="ios">Cancel</span>
        <ion-icon name="md-close" showWhen="android"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```